# HTTPConnectionURL in UTF-8 for Webservice POST

Tags: java, web-services, encoding

I'm creating a client for a webservice that I don't control. I'm trying to do a POST. Here's my code.

```
        String generatedUrl = generateURL(); //Logic that creates the whole url
        logger.debug("URL = "+generatedUrl);
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        URL url;
        try {
            url = new URL(generatedUrl);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=utf-8");

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8"));
            String inputLine;


            while((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null){
                response.append(inputLine);
            }
            in.close();
            logger.debug("RESPONSE = "+response.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Error = "+e);
        }   
        return response.toString();
```

The problem is when I'm sending japanese characters. The URL contains the right chars, but on the webservice side, only a bunch of weird symbols are received. If I hit the generated URL using the browser, it works just fine. It seems I can't get my POST to go through in UTF-8. Any ideas?

Comment: try encoding generated url, URLEncoder.encode(generatedUrl, "UTF-8");

Comment: Tried it... but didn't work :/

Comment: when writing data aren't you using, "BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream, "UTF-8"));" to write using UTF-8?

Comment: Yes, it's right there in the code. And I just checked the default charset for the connection and it says UTF-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of encoding the whole query, I only had to use the URLEncoder.encode() method on the parts of the query that were having issues (like, for example, a name). So, it kinda ended up looking like this

```
url = .... + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8) + ...
```